# Python 3.6 throwing logging error as 'AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'find''

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to configure logging like below

```
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import sys
tz = datetime.utcnow().isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z'
fmt = tz + ' %(levelname)s %(filename)s %(threadName)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)d %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(
             format=fmt,
             datefmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',
             handlers=[logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)],
             level=logging.INFO)
```

But whenever I am trying to do a log. It is throwing the below error

```
>>> logging.info("debraj")
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 994, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 840, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 578, in format
    if self.usesTime():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 546, in usesTime
    return self._style.usesTime()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 388, in usesTime
    return self._fmt.find(self.asctime_search) >= 0
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'find'
Call stack:
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Message: 'debraj'
Arguments: ()
```

- Python Version 3.6 OS
- Ubuntu 18.04

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: That looks like your actual code has a trailing comma on the line where `fmt` is assigned, making it a tuple instead of string.

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed the problem.

Comment: @jasonharper - Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it to mark the question resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jasonharper answered as comment above

> That looks like your actual code has a trailing comma on the line
> where fmt is assigned, making it a tuple instead of string